# Pushing objects into an array in ReactJS does not stop

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, mongodb, reactjs

In my React app, I need to perform a task where I retrieve an Audio URL from my database that looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a2b903abcf92a362080db4f"
    },
    "name": "test",
    "playList": [
        {
            "url": "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/a3fd5f178b7eb68b9dba4da9711f05a714efc966?cid=ed36a056ee504173a3889b2e55cbd461",
            "artist": "Lil Pump",
            "songName": "D Rose",
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5a2c5631e54ca10eb84a0053"
            }
        },
        {
            "url": "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/155643656a12e570e4dda20a9a24d9da765b9ac5?cid=ed36a056ee504173a3889b2e55cbd461",
            "artist": "Tee Grizzley",
            "songName": "From The D To The A (feat. Lil Yachty)",
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5a2c5631e54ca10eb84a0054"
            }
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

And create a new Audio (HTML5) object with the URL parsed from the database, put it into an array, then implement a play list with the songs in the array.

What I do to retrieve the URL from the database is something like:

```
- I made a search bar where I can search music tracks
- Clicking the item for search result adds the object to the DB shown above
- As the data is added to the DB, I try to parse that in my componentDidUdpdate.
```

So my code for retrieving the data looks like:

**(I used two same snippets of code in both componentWillMount (for loading e existing data) and componentDidMount (for getting the newly added data)**

```
componentWillMount() {

    console.log('Component WILL MOUNT!')

    axios.get('/channels').then( (res) => {
        //console.log(res.data.data.playList);
        //let playlists = [];
        res.data.data.playList.map((value, key) => this.playlists.push(new Audio(value.url)));

        this.setState((prevState) => {
            return { audioList: this.playlists, categories: res.data.data.playList }
        }, () => console.log(this.playlists));

    }).catch( (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });

}
```

componentDidUpdate

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){

    console.log("did update")

    axios.get('/channels').then( (res) => {
        //console.log(res.data.data.playList);
        //let playlists = [];
        res.data.data.playList.map((value, key) => this.playlists.push(new Audio(value.url)));

        this.setState((prevState) => {
            return { audioList: this.playlists, categories: res.data.data.playList }
        }, () => console.log(this.playlists));

    }).catch( (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

However when I add a new Audio object, it never stops adding the object according to my console log, creating a list with infinite length.

[image]

I just want to have three exact objects that is in the DB.

How may I solve this issue?

Please help!

**EDIT**

So, when I click the searched item (song JSON), it parses the artist name, track name, and the song URL and adds it to the DB with the following code.

```
clickMusicHandler() {

    //console.log(this.props.channel);

    axios.put('/channels/'+'test', {

        playList: {
            songName: this.props.track.name,
            artist: this.props.track.artists[0].name,
            url: this.props.track.preview_url
        }
    })
        .then((res)=>{
        console.log("added song");
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    });   

}
```

After that, I am updating the list of the added song by doing

```
<SidebarCategory categories={this.state.categories} />
```

Where SidebarCategory is just

```
render() {
    return (

            <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-sm-10">
                      {this.props.categories.map((category, key) =>(
                        <div key={key}><span>{category.songName}</span>
                         - <span>{category.artist}</span></div>
                      ))}
                  </div>
            </div>



    );
}
```

This is just the visualization. What I eventually want to do is use the list of Audio objects that I created to make a play-able song list by using commands like songlist[index].play() and pause(), etc.

Comment: its because `componentDidUpdate` is invoked immediately after updating occurs, if you do setState it will again trigger `componentDidUpdate` and repeat .... "Infinite loop". Can you explain this 'As the data is added to the DB, I try to parse that in my componentDidUdpdate'? what you want to do once data added to db?

Comment: Why u cant use componentDidMount?

Comment: @MayankShukla thanks for the comment. I added my response in the EDIT. Please check!

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN is that what I am supposed to use?